# Stubing a model constant for assosiation (undefined method `relation_delegate_class')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have a `Lesson` model which is assosiated with `Permission` model:

**`app/models/lesson.rb`**:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :class_name => 'Permission', as: :permissible, dependent: :destroy
  ...

  def create_permissions
    Permission::DEFAULTS[:lesson].each do |action, value|
      ..
    end
  end
```

**`app/models/permission.rb`**:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULTS = {
    lesson: {some_more_action: 15}
  }

  belongs_to :permissible, polymorphic: true
end
```

I used RSpec `stub_const` method to [stub a nested defined constant](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant#stub-nested-constant):

**`spec/models/lesson_spec.rb`**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Lesson, :type => :model do
  describe "#create_permissions" do
    let!(:lesson) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :lesson }

    before(:each) do
      stub_const('Permission::DEFAULTS', {lesson: {some_action: 5}})
    end

    it 'should create permissions' do
      lesson.create_permissions

      permission = lesson.permissions.first

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But the spec fails with error:

```
Failure/Error: permission = lesson.permissions.first
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Permission:Module
 # /home/install/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:112:in `relation_class_for'
 # /home/install/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `create'
 # /home/install/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `reader'
 # /home/install/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `permissions'
 # ./spec/models/lesson_spec.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It looks as if `permissions` are no longer rails assosiatiated with lesson model. Any ideas on how to get this round.

Gem versions: `rspec-3.3.0`, `rspec-rails-3.3.3`, `rails-4.2.3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look to this error message:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Permission:Module
```

`Permission` is described as a `Module` here, not as a `Class`. I think this happens because at the moment of stubbing nested const, `Permission` class has not been loaded yet, and RSpec has to stub it too via `Module`.

Try this as a workaround:

```
before(:each) do
  Permission # load real ActiveRecord Permission class
  stub_const('Permission::DEFAULTS', {lesson: {some_action: 5}})
end
```

**EDIT**: As a side note, I don't think that exposing nested constants to other classes is a good idea, you have little control over the constant (just changing a name or value) and you can't wrap any behavior like you do it with a method. I recommend to change public `Permission`'s API to a using a method, it will also be easier to stub:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULTS = {
    lesson: {some_more_action: 15}
  }

  def self.defaults
    DEFAULTS
  end    
end
```

And in your spec:

```
before(:each) do
  allow(Permission).to receive(:defaults).and_return(lesson: {some_action: 5})
end
```

Comment: That's a hit! Had similar thoughts but didn't know that this will cause RSpec to change behavior. Thank you! Will wrap it up in a method.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that I came upon was just to set constant explicitly in an example:

```
before(:each) do
  Permission::DEFAULTS = {lesson: {some_action: 5}}
end
```

But I don't feel it's a good idea. It rises a couple of warnings also:

```
spec/models/lesson_spec.rb:279: warning: already initialized constant Permission::DEFAULTS
app/models/permission.rb:2: warning: previous definition of DEFAULTS was here
```